# fetching data frm remote server backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, fetch

I have an URL to some server resources that should be fetched into my app with backbone.js.
I have this piece of code which I guess will be helpful,

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "http://anexampleproject/api/players",
    model: MyModel
});

var myCollection = new MyCollection();
myCollection.fetch({
    success: function(){

    },
    error: function(){

    }
});
```

but I dont know how to connect this function to the click event of a given html element and how to define a container where the data should be rendered. 
If you can help me it'd be great. Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

You for handling click event you can use backbone view in your project.
See this:

[**Backbone.View**](http://backbonejs.org/#View)

And here have examples to create model, collections and how to connect their with view:

[**backbone-Collection based on JSON + View - Part1**](http://blog.joelberghoff.com/2012/07/22/backbone-js-tutorial-part-1/)

[**backbone-Creating an App View - Part2**](http://blog.joelberghoff.com/2012/07/23/backbone-js-tutorial-part-2/)

[**backbone-Creating a Paginated View - part3**](http://blog.joelberghoff.com/2012/07/24/backbone-js-tutorial-part-3/)

Comment: thanks for the links, I tried it to implement in my project but it failed. I have ordered tha book about backbone but i have to do this feature until monday. Could you help somehow ?